# How do you enable scrolling on a non-editable SwiftUI TextField?

Tags: swiftui, scroll, textview

I want to have a multi-line TextField in my multi-platform SwiftUI app that is scrollable and selectable, but not editable. That's easy to do in UIKit/AppKit, but not so much with SwiftUI.

If I disable the text field, it also disables scrolling and selection. For MacOS, it also makes the text gray and very hard to read.

Shouldn't there be an editable property for TextFields like there is with UITextFields? (I haven't worked with AppKit in a while and don't remember the specific setting there, but do remember that there is one.)

Below is some sample code for a multi-platform SwiftUI app where the textField is either scrollable & editable, or neither scrollable nor editable:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text: String = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus. Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a. At quis risus sed vulputate. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id. Blandit turpis cursus in hac. Et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a.

Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tortor consequat id porta nibh. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis. Mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Libero enim sed faucibus turpis.

Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus. Donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. Et pharetra pharetra massa massa. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Vitae et leo duis ut diam. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin. Nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut.

Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. At varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus.
"""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .lineLimit(20)
                .disabled(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/true/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) // This line prevents scrolling
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.all, 2)
                .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 30)
                .padding()
#if os(iOS) //For iPhone/iPad
                .border(.gray)
#endif
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Text?

Answer (score 1):

So I don't think you can have a SwiftUI TextField that's selectable and scrollable but not editable. (At least I couldn't make it work.)

The right answer is to put a `Text` `View` inside a `ScrollView` and give the `ScrollView` a border. Something like this:

```
ScrollView() {
    Text(userSettings.wordList)
        .lineLimit(nil)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .padding(.all, 2)
        .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200)
}
.border(.gray)
```